# "Attitudine ___ lavorare in gruppo": qual è la preposizione corretta?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Quale preposizione si deve usare in questa frase?

> Ha una grande attitudine  ___  lavorare in gruppo.

"Per", "a", "in" oppure altro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In" sicuramente no, io userei "a" e "per" in quest'ordine di preferenza.

**Edit**: dopo averci pensato un po', anche se "attitudine per" è sicuramente comprensibile e nessuno si sorprenderebbe, io userei sicuramente "a".

**Edit2**: però effettivamente dipende. Per esempio se sostituiamo il verbo con un sostantivo, anche "per" suona bene, anzi forse perfino meglio:

> Ha una grande attitudine per il lavoro di gruppo

Comment: Abbiamo già a disposizione la cronologia delle modifiche, non serve che tu le menzioni nel testo. Danno solo fastidio e rendono la risposta più contorta.

Comment: Lo so, ho usato la funzione di edit molte altre volte. In questo caso volevo che fosse evidente il ragionamento che ho seguito.

Answer (score 4):

[Attitudine](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/attitudine_1.shtml):

> - **Predisposizione per una particolare attività** mentale o fisica, (sin.)  **vocazione, inclinazione, talento**: avere a. per lo studio; idoneità: certificato medico di a. al lavoro.

La preposizione maggiormente usata con attitudine è "a" come risulta evidente da [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attitudine%20a%2C%20%20attitudine%20per%2C%20attitudine%20verso&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattitudine%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattitudine%20per%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattitudine%20verso%3B%2Cc0).
"Per" e "verso"  sono corrette ma meno diffuse. Il contesto è importante e la scelta della preposizione  dipende dal  significato che il termine assume in quel contesto.

- Attitudine ***a*** fare nuove conoscenze: tendenza/inclinazione  a fare nuove conoscenze.
- Attitudine ***per*** le cose nuove: inclinazione/curiosità per le cose nuove.
- Attitudine ***verso*** le persone di potere: atteggiamento/predisposizione nei confronti delle persone di potere.

Answer (score 2):

L'unica forma corretta è "Ha una grande attitudine a lavorare in gruppo", perché "lavorare in gruppo" è una subordinata. In caso di complemento, sarebbe stato "Ha una grande attitudine al lavoro di gruppo". In quest'ultimo caso è anche corretto "per", ma non nel caso da te portato.